# Override "Permission denied [...] on cross-origin object" for page loaded in iframe hosted on localhost

Tags: javascript, iframe, window.parent

I am writing a set of controls in HTML & JS which I am using to extend the functionality of a site I use but do not control.  I've loaded the site in an `iframe` to control it via the controls hosted on `localhost`.  The page being loaded has its own scripts, which include a mechanism which climbs up the `window` tree until it's at the top window and attempts to run its subsequent code in that context, resulting in a message akin to "*Permission denied [...] on cross-origin object*".

I'm not clear on what I can do (if anything) in Firefox, Chrome *et al* to work around this.  How would I trick the content I'm loading in the `iframe` into believing its whole world is only there in the frame, so that `window.parent` returns itself from the frame's context?

Answer (score 0):

This is dangerous behavior, but, assuming you're set on the setup you've got now, probably the simplest thing to do is get to the topmost window in your nested page and then iterate back downward as long as some condition of the window doesn't match what you expect - e.g. `window.location.host` not being your app's typical host.

Comment: – The only problem is I don't have control of the script that's searching for ```window.top```. I was hoping there was a way to make the content of the ```iframe```, which includes said script, to believe that it was being loaded as if I'd simply typed it's URL in the address bar, i.e. for the content of the ```iframe``` to believe it is its own top window.